# Eclipse: "Open Declaration" no longer working

Tags: eclipse

I used to open the file containing the declaration of a function in PHP using either F3 or the context menu. This is no longer working.

Maybe this has to do with recently installed "New Software", other extensions. How could I find out which one might cause it?

There are no messages in the status line.

Comment: I assume you tried restarting Eclipse?

Comment: Yes, I did. (I have to write a little more to make this a valid comment)